# what is the maximum time windows service wait to process stop request and how to request for additional time

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have written a windows service in c# that process a lot data. when we stop it try for sometime 20/30 seconds and then throws exception.

I want to implement ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() in OnStop event.

I want to know the exact timeout after which windows service throws the exception, so that I can request additional time just before it.

I searched but did not find this default stop timeout value.

Comment: IIRC it's 30 seconds - http://www.itgeekdiary.com/increase-the-service-timeout-period/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wrote the following code to achieve it.

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
  int timeout = 10000;
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyTask());
  while (!task.Wait(timeout))
  {
      RequestAdditionalTime(timeout);
  }
}
```

The above code starts a Task in Parallel to the main thread (Task start running immediately), next line is to check if task is completed or not every 10 seconds and if it is not completed it requests additional 10 seconds and keep checking till task get completed.

Comment: @Imran Rizvi,  Is there any total time limit in the  RequestAdditionalTime? First 10 seconds, second 10 seconds, three 10 senconds... Can it keep 1 hour?

Comment: Chris Kline answer provides a lot of useful details about the inner workings that is still relevant since it was posted 4 years ago and 7 years since OP.

Comment: This code contains subtle issue: If you request the same amount of extra delay as the loop standoff delay, and the Task.Wait slips, your thread may still be killed far sooner than the hard system timeout.

Comment: if I try to retrieve timeout from config variable int timeout = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WaitTime"]); windows service not liking and it's not starting the windows service even. Anybody faced this issue?

Answer (score 30):

## Different settings for OS restart

Though a number of people have mentioned the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout` registry key, according to [this "Service Control Handler" article from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx) that registry entry **only** controls the max amount of time a service can take to shut down **when Windows itself is being shut down or restarted**:

> <...> to prevent a service from stopping shutdown, there is a limit
>   to how long the service controller waits. If the service is being shut
>   down through the Services snap-in, the limit is 125 seconds. If the
>   operating system is rebooting, the time limit is specified in the
>   `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` value <...>

**If Windows is not in the process of restarting or shutting down**, then the **default** amount of time Windows will wait for a service to shut down is 30 seconds. However, applications can make requests for additional time, which will be honored up to 125 seconds total (summed across all requests).

On Windows Server 2003 and later, **this default timeout can be changed** via the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout` registry key, as described in [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922918/a-service-does-not-start-and-events-7000-and-7011-are-logged-in-window) (and [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/622432/how-do-i-increase-windows-service-startup-timeout)). It's not clear if this applies to Windows 7/8/10, as the article only mentions server versions.

**If a restart/shutdown has been initiated** on the machine, the `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` registry key value (if present) specifies the maximum amount of time Windows will allow the application will be allowed, overriding the OS default.

Presumably this is so that applications cannot arbitrarily delay shutdown beyond the default (or what the administrator specified via the `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` registry entry).

Comment: It seems that the default timeout on my system is 125 seconds for stopping a service though the "Services" mmc.  Changing ServicesPipeTimeout doesn't seem to have any affect.  Set to 30,000 ms and it still gives the service 125 seconds to stop.

Comment: I believe the `ServicesPipeTimeout` is rather only used during service startup. Specifically, it might be related to the ["wait hint"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-servicemain-function) a service is supposed to specify estimating the duration from _start pending_ to _running_.

Answer (score 5):

It's set in the registry on subkey:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
```

with string value `WaitToKillServiceTimeout`. If not defined, it defaults to 20000 (ms). On my machine it seems to be set to 12000 (12s). I have never touched it.

Answer (score 1):

Just always perform the `RequestAdditionalTime`, with the maximum time you expect your service to need for shutdown. It is not an error to finish earlier than predicted.

Comment: service process data based on received data and that is unknown sized, so i don't know how much time it will take to stop. it should not stop before processing all the data

Comment: Yes, it should. Received data should be stored in a queue on disk (so nothing is lost if the power drops out) and processed from there. The main reasons I am stopping a service are a) reboots (which I want to get over with quickly), and b) if the service appears to malfunction (in which case I certainly do not want it to process the remaining requests).

Answer (score 0):

by default I believe it is 12000 milliseconds, to change it you need to access registry
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout and change the value

but you can define your own time out if you want to start it or stop it programming 
here you define your own time out for starting

```
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
```

and here you define your own time out for stopping

```
 TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
 service.Stop();
 service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
```

Comment: This will not help when working with built-in Windows tools like `sc.exe` or the "Services" mmc addin.

Comment: true, but what i included is to do stop and restart grammatically

Comment: Then you should indicate that fact. Because strictly, this is not an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: where to write your code? i have OnStop overriden method to process data , in which i am not writing .Stop anywhere..