# Repeated Stopping and Starting Windows Service

Tags: windows, service

I wrote a PowerShell script to remotely stop and start windows services.
The problem is that, one of the windows services takes too long to stop after the first stop/start. When I stop and start the service for the first time, it works good but if I try to stop the service as soon as the service is running again, it takes 3mins to stop. Does it take time for a service to recover from stop/start?

Thanks

Comment: This depends entirely on the specific service.  If you tell us which one it is, we might be able to suggest the reason.

Answer (score 0):

No - services stop on their own time. There are limitations though on how long they have. You are allowed a certain amount of time. If I write a service that does nothing on shut down, it will immediately shut down. However when you are dealing with other serives you didn't write, there may very well be reasons they need to clean up, wait for pending connections to finish, etc. and that is what I believe you are running up against.

---

From: [what is the maximum time windows service wait to process stop request and how to request for additional time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454054/what-is-the-maximum-time-windows-service-wait-to-process-stop-request)

Though a number of people have mentioned the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout registry key, according to this "Service Control Handler" article from Microsoft that registry entry only controls the max amount of time a service can take to shut down when Windows itself is being shut down or restarted:

<...> to prevent a service from stopping shutdown, there is a limit to how long the service controller waits. If the service is being shut down through the Services snap-in, the limit is 125 seconds. If the operating system is rebooting, the time limit is specified in the WaitToKillServiceTimeout value <...>
If the machine is not being restarted/shutdown, then the default amount of time Windows will wait for a service to shut down is 30 seconds. However, applications can request additional time, and will be allowed up to 125 seconds total.