# How exceptions are handled in catch block when application is shutting down?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, application-shutdown

I have an async function which performs possibly long lasting request.

```
private Task Request(CancellationToken ct) => { some HTTP call }
```

I call this function inside a try-catch block like this:

```
try {
    await Request(CancellationToken.None);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    await CleanupDb();
}

private Task CleanupDb() { call to local DB }
```

My app is delivered as a Windows service. I faced that if the service is stopped, a `TaskCancelledException` occurs inside `Request`. What happens next? How will catch block work then? From my app logs it looks like that the catch block was executed (the `CleanupDb` is the only one who could do a specific action). But I was not succesful to reproduce it. I added logging before and after `CleanupDb`, and I saw only before but not after...

Comment: try to request additional time - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454054 | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0